# How to remove duplicates from json in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a MySQL, PHP code as follows.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM shipschedule WHERE ship_date BETWEEN '2016-08-01' AND '2016-8-31'";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$e = array();

while($r = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $rows = array();
    $rows['title'] = $r['title'];
    $rows['start'] = $r['ship_date'];
    array_push($e, $rows);
}
echo json_encode($e);
```

The above php code echos

```
[{"title":"111","start":"2016-08-10"},
 {"title":"111","start":"2016-08-10"},
 {"title":"111","start":"2016-08-10"},
 {"title":"222","start":"2016-08-17"},
 {"title":"222","start":"2016-08-17"},
 {"title":"222","start":"2016-08-16"}]
```

My question is how I can echo the above as follow instead. Please see that duplicate start dates will be removed by title.

```
[{"title":"111","start":"2016-08-10"},
 {"title":"222","start":"2016-08-17"},
 {"title":"222","start":"2016-08-16"}]
```

title 111 has the same 3 start dates, and I need to display it like

```
{"title":"111","start":"2016-08-10"},
```

title 222 has the same 2 start dates, and I need to display it like

```
 {"title":"222","start":"2016-08-17"},
 {"title":"222","start":"2016-08-16"}]
```

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` - will remove the duplicate results from the query return.

Comment: why do it in php? you're doing a query. have the query eliminate dupes so you don't waste time retrieving data only to delete it again in php.

Comment: You are right. Somehow I focused PHP and overlooked mysql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could prevent receiving duplicates, and reduce requesting unnecessary data by adjusting your query.

`SELECT DISTINCT title, start FROM ...`

Answer (score 2):

It would be much easier (and probably faster too) to just get the right (unique) data from MySQL. This can be achieved with the `distinct` modifier:

```
SELECT DISTINCT title, start
FROM   shipschedule
WHERE  ship_date BETWEEN '2016-08-01' AND '2016-8-31'
```